# Can 5xx/4xx errors for resource loads be hidden in the console?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, console

I've been updating one of my pet projects (a real-time photo site) and I'm trying to solve a small pet-peeve type of problem.

When the images are loading and the remote server fails in some way (returns a 500, a 404, etc) if the console is open you can see the failed requests.

Even when I capture the errors, the failed requests still show up. While this doesn't present any performance or issues with the app itself, it does annoy me a bit.

Wondering if anyone has an idea how to stop the logs from appearing, or if its just something baked into the browsers.

When I say console, I'm talking about the developer toolbars in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox (Firebug).

Here's one way that I load the images. Basically doing a pre-load and appending on complete:

```
$(new Image())
    .load(function(){
        $(this).appendTo( $('#container') );
    })
    .error(function(err){
        //do whatever here. try/catch insider here doesn't stop the error from showing  
    })
    .attr('src', imgsrc);
```

Comment: The load method is actually "generating" the HTTP request error so the try/catch needs to wrap it instead.

Comment: I think you're on to something there. But since requests in this case are being generated when the src attribute of the Image object is changed, I don't see a way to capture the error at such a low level. I did just try and wrap the img.src = imgsrc; in a try/catch but it ain't workin. Good idea though.

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    $(new Image())
    .load(function(){
        $(this).appendTo( $('#container') );
    })
    .attr('src', imgsrc);
} catch(e) {
    //code here
}
```

You could try that.

Comment: Nope, that's what I meant when I tried try/catch in various places (wrapping, inner, etc). Still shows the resource load errors. The error events *fire*, so I can trap those for reporting and whatnot, but console still shows the failures.

Comment: ah so you are trying to simply prevent error reporting in js consoles.... I don't think you can control this as it's built into the browser, and they don't open options up for this.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm thinking too. I think its just baked in.